# Image of $g(z)/f(z)$ if $|f(z)-g(z)|\lt |f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, curves

> Let $C$ be a simple closed contour lying entirely within a domain $D$. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are analytic in $D$ and that $|f(z)-g(z)|\lt |f(z)|$ for all $z$ on $C$. Then $|F(z)-1|\lt 1$, where $F(z)=g(z)/f(z)$. This inequality shows that the image $C'$ of the curve $C$ under the mapping $w=F(z)$ is a closed path.

How does "$C'$ is a closed path" follow from the inequality? I can only confirm that $C'$ lies within the open disk $|w-1|\lt 1$.

Comment: If $C$ is a closed path then $C'=F(C)$ is trivially a closed path as well. The inequality ensures that $C'$ is contained in the disk $|w-1|< 1$, as you say.

Comment: @Martin R I don't see why it is trivial. Please explain.

Comment: If the startpoint and the endpoint of $C$ are equal then the same is true for $F(C)$.

Comment: Does the problem actually read "is a closed path", or is it "is a closed path in $D(1,1)$"or some such???

Comment: @David C. Ulrich It reads only "is a closed path".

Comment: @Nomas: Then it is an error in the book (or at least very misleading).

Comment: @Martin R I agree. I understand it now, though.